# Flask SocketIO Notifications

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I currently try to figure out how to make socketIO works for push notifications.
I don't know how to send database informations to socket and how to translate in Jquery...

What I'm trying to do is to compare the last time the users saw the notification dropdown, and if the timestamp of the user is older than a database notification, I want to make a span with the number of notifications not seen.

Here is my route.py :

```
@socketio.on('notif')
def handle_message():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        notif = Notification.query.filter(
        Notification.timestamp < current_user.last_seen_notification)
        n = len(notif)
    send(n)

@app.route('/notification', methods=["POST"])
def notification():
    current_user.last_seen_notification = datetime.datetime.now()
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Ok'
```

I have my html :

```
    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" id="notifbtn">
<i class="nc-icon nc-planet"></i>
<span class="notification"></span>
<span class="d-lg-none">Notification</span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notification 1</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notification 2</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notification 3</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notification 4</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another notification</a>
</ul>
</li>
```

and my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#notifbtn").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/notification'
        })
    });

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

    socket.on('notif', function() {
        $('.notification').text(n);
        console.log('Received message');
    });
});
```

My javascript with the dropdown works good, when the user click on the dropdown, his last_seen_notification variable is updated.

But I don't know how to make the socketio works.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how you are planning to do this. Why are you mixing Ajax with Socket.IO? I would use one or the other. If you want to use Socket.IO the server should emit the `notif` event whenever a new notification is added. The message should include the notification count. And when the user clicks the notification dropdown the client should emit another event to the server, asking to update the last seen notification.

Comment: How I can send event to the server with SocketIO the tutorial and the documentation are really poor, all I see is chat examples so I cant understand how to do this properly

Comment: A chat application sends events to the server, so it matches what you need to do. You can also look at the examples in the Flask-SocketIO repository, which are not chat apps but much simpler.

Comment: I can't see how I can manage to do that..  I did the chat app to see how it works but I can't success to adapt it to my needs

Comment: @Senseikaii just clone [repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat) and customize as you wish.